# Where do I place the Apache license 2 in phonegap app?

Tags: apache, cordova, adobe

Where do I place the Apache 2.0 License in my Phonegap app? Do I just copy and paste that one part and place it in a txt file and stick it in my WWW folder? Or does it need to appear in the app itself somewhere? Im very new to this stuff so I apologize if I sound like an amateur.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to place the license anywhere until you don't and you shouldn't move it from the original cordova files.

See the license here:

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Comment: ahh so everything is in place already withing the cordova file? sweet